# Password AutoFill inserts password into parent UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, autofill, password-autofill

I am using a UINavigationController to push multiple view controllers.
At one point, the user is able to use Password AutoFill for setting a new password. The password is also being added to textfields for parent view controllers.

###### View controller stack

`UINavigationController -> View Controller A -> View Controller B -> View Controller C`

View Controller A has two fields for email/password, of type UITextField.
View Controller B has one field for email, of type UITextField.
View Controller C has two fields for password/confirmPassword, of type UITextField.

###### The problem

When the password is reset in View Controller C, the View Controller is popped and I observe in the delegate function `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` that the newly made password is being inserted into the email field for View Controller B AND the email field for View Controller A. Resulting in the input fields having a value something similar to `bob@company.comNEWLY-MADE-PASSWORD`. Why the password is being inserted into a UITextField with `.textContentType = .emailAddress` in the first place, is also confusing to me.

Why is Password AutoFill attempting to be *smart* and insert the new password into the field of the parent view controllers? This is somewhat of a headache for me, resulting in some wonky checks in the delegate function to deny the insertion of a password.

In response to the comment made by El Tomato:
Apple uses the term "popped" in their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller) to describe what happends when you call `popViewController(animated:)`.

There are no view controllers presented. They are all pushed to the stack managed by the [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller), as stated in the header -> `View controller stack`.

There is no relevant code to present, Password AutoFill is resolved by heuristics hidden from the developer, this is a built-in feature made by Apple.

###### Workaround

I found a workaround to prevent the generated password from being inserted into UITextField of parent view controller. Hopefully this will help others who are experiencing the same problem.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.split(separator: "-").count == 3 {
        // A password autofill triggered from ResetPasswordViewController, this seems like a bug and I could not find any documentation for this.
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: "the View Controller is popped"  What does 'a view controller is popped' mean?  The user sees a view controller as a class per se?  Or are you talking about a sheet presented over the current screen?  And what's stopping you from showing all relevant lines of code?

Comment: @ElTomato I've added some more info at the bottom of my question, please revise it.

Comment: @Laffen did you ever get this resolved? I'm running into the exact same scenario: A different text field is getting auto completed

Comment: @A.Andino Not excactly, I found a workaround to prevent the password from being added into the UITextField. See the workaround in the updated question.

Comment: @Laffen I managed to figure out my issue. I am using SwiftUI so maybe it doesn't apply to you, but I realized that when navigating away from the screen, the focus was still on a textfield on the previous screen so when I navigated back, the textfield would get selected automatically and autofilled. What I ended up doing was resign first responder when navigating away from all screens, and that stopped the autofill